# Capturar el error del catch - reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Estoy ya varios días y no doy con la solución.

Tengo un servicio en una pagina. Se carga la información donde se ejecuta el `try` y el `catch`. En el `catch` tengo que capturar el error e igualarlo a un código único que viene en la respuesta. En el `catch` capturo el código sin problemas. El tema es que el código del `catch` se encentra en una parte del proyecto.

El botón que dispara el evento está en otro archivo, donde esta el *form*. El botón esta en el *front* donde tengo que mostrar ese mensaje de error y evitar que suceda el envío. Puedo dejar ambos códigos a ver si me pueden ayudar.

Lo que tengo que evitar es que el campo `email` valide, y no envíe el correo si ya existe. Para verificar uso el código que esta en el `catch` dentro del `if`. Ese código indica que el correo ya existe. Con eso se pude igualar si el correo existe.

Mi clase addCollaborator:

```
// codigo del servicio
export const addCollaborator = async (collaborator) => {
// adds the received collaborator

    const data = {     
        persona:{
            nombre:collaborator.name,
            apellidoPaterno:collaborator.surname,
            correo:collaborator.user,
            celular:collaborator.phone
        },
        corredor:{
            identificador:3
        },
        grupo:{
            codigo: collaboratorAccessShortText(collaborator.access)
        }   
    }

    let addCollaboratorPromise;
    
    try {
        addCollaboratorPromise = await HTTP_REQUEST.postBrokers('BROKERS', URL.addCollaborators, helpers.getBodyAmplify(data));
        if (addCollaboratorPromise) {
            console.log(addCollaboratorPromise);
        }
    } catch (error) {
        const request = Object.values(error);
        const message = request[2];
        const respuesta = message.data.status.error.httpCode;
        const mensaje =  message.data.status.error.messages[0];
        setErrorTag(respuesta, mensaje, "trackError");
        if (message.data.status.error.code === 'SEG010210') {
            //alert('correo existe');
            console.log('el error', message.data.status.error.code)
            return false;

        }
    }
    return addCollaboratorPromise;
}
```

Y esta es mi clase AddEditCollaborator:

```
export default class AddEditCollaborator extends Component {

confirmBtnClick() {
  this.props.confirmBtnClick(this.state.fields);
    }
    
 }

render = () => {
        return (
            <Modal
                className={this.componentClasses}
                isVisible={this.props.isVisible}
                valueChanged={() => this.closeClick()}
                fullwidth={true}>
                {this.title}
                <div className="content-scroll">
                    <div className="dv-clbtr-data">
                        <Textfield
                            className="txt-field"
                            placeholder="Nombre(s)"
                            value={this.state.fields.name}
                            valueChanged={v => this.setField('name', v)} />
                        <Textfield
                            className="txt-field"
                            placeholder="Apellido paterno"
                            value={this.state.fields.surname}
                            valueChanged={v => this.setField('surname', v)} />
                        <Textfield
                            className="txt-field"
                            placeholder="Correo electronico"
                            error={!this.props.newUserMailAvailable}
                            errorMsg={this.mailErrorMsg()}
                            onBlur={'email'}
                            description="Este correo será requerido en caso que el colaborador necesite recuperar su contraseña. Prefiere un correo laboral."
                            value={this.state.fields.user}
                            readOnly={!this.props.newCollaborator}
                            valueChanged={v => this.setField('user', v)} />
                        <Textfield
                            className="txt-field"
                            placeholder="Celular"
                            onBlur={'numero'}
                            value={this.state.fields.phone}
                            opcional={true}
                            valueChanged={v => this.setField('phone', v)} />
                    </div>
                    <div className="dv-btns">
                        <Button
                            btnStyle="2"
                            click={() => this.closeClick()}>
                            CANCELAR
                        </Button>
                        <Button
                            className="add-btn"
                            disabled={!this.confirmBtnEnabled()}
                            click={() => this.confirmBtnClick()}>
                            {this.confirmBtnText}
                        </Button>
                    </div>
                    }
                    )
```

Comment: ¿Puedes formular mejor la pregunta para poder ayudarte? Esta pregunta está formulada muy a la ligera

Comment: tienes la clase [error](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Error) de javascript para hacer este tipo de cosas.

Comment: Por favor podrias poner un ejemplo de como hacerlo. el problema es que se tiene en 2 archivos separados.